# Optimal Matching: Error Warning, but the Output seems fine

Tags: r

I performed optimal matching via the MatchIt and optmatch packages:

```
library(MatchIt)
library(optmatch)
data(lalonde)

optimal <- matchit(treat ~ age + educ + black, data = lalonde, method = "optimal", ratio = 2)
smry.opti <- summary(optimal, standardize = TRUE)
```

The summary seems fine, but I always get the following warning message:

```
"In fullmatch(d, min.controls = ratio, max.controls = ratio, omit.fraction = (n0 -  :
Without 'data' argument the order of the match is not guaranteed
to be the same as your original data."
```

I've found some posts, which described similar problems. Some people replied that the warning message should just be ignored:
https://lists.gking.harvard.edu/pipermail/matchit/2013-August/000538.html

Should I change something in my code or could I just ignore the warning message?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: IMO, warnings should **never** be ignored.   I think you got lucky here because you got the correct result.  But sometimes you'll get the wrong result with a warning.  Best to find out what's causing the warning and change accordingly.  In your case the warning says the `data` argument is missing so I'd start there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've simulated my own data and used exactly the same dataset without any problems for several other matching algorithms. Furthermore, I received the same warning message in the given example, in which I used a completely different dataset. The same problem appears when Im using the fullmatch method. Both methods (optimal and fullmatch) are using the optmatch package, so I guess the problem is due to the package. But unfortunately I cant figure out how to solve it.

Comment: *Note:* I've submitted a [ticket on GitHub](https://github.com/kosukeimai/MatchIt/issues/18)

Comment: Thanks @jaySf! It would be very nice, if you could post in this thread, once you received an answer!

Comment: Since the ticket is not processed for one month now, I'd suggest that someone makes a kind of comment there which confirms the issue--in order to emphasize the matter!

Comment: @jaySf just commented at github