# R - Matchit - Propensity Score Matching - Discard function not working

Tags: r, matching

I am using the MatchIt package on the LaLonde data-set and the discard argument is generating two types of errors. (The code works if I do not use the discard argument). In both cases, it is not clear how to resolve the problems....

The first issue is when I try `discard = "hull.control"`

```
m.opt1 <- matchit(treat ~ inc.re74 + inc.re75 + education + nonwhite + 
  age + nodegree, data = cps_controls, method = "optimal", ratio=1, 
  discard="hull.control")
```

This error message is produced....

```
Loading required namespace: WhatIf
Preprocessing data ...
Performing convex hull test ...
Error in mclapply(1:m, in_ch, mc.cores = mc.cores) : 
'mc.cores' > 1 is not supported on Windows
```

The second issue is when I try `discard = "control"`

```
Error in d[i, ] <- abs(d1[i] - d0) : 
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Is there a way to address either of these?  Thanks!!

Comment: are you using "lalonde" data or "cps_controls" data? for the latter please add data example that we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Hi I was using cps_controls but just tried it again with the lalonde data-set available in the MatchIt package -

Comment: And I received the same error for the first problem above and a new error for the second problem mentioned - here is the code I used - again it works if I do not use the discard argument:  m.opt <- matchit(treat ~ re74 + re75 + educ + black + hispan + age,  data = lalonde, method = "optimal", ratio = 2)

Comment: Here is the new error message. Thanks!       Error in fullmatch.matrix(d, min.controls = ratio, max.controls = ratio,  : 
  negative 'omit.fraction' with 'min.controls' >= 2 not permitted
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In optmatch::fullmatch(d, min.controls = ratio, max.controls = ratio,  :
  Without 'data' argument the order of the match is not guaranteed
    to be the same as your original data.
2: In fullmatch.matrix(d, min.controls = ratio, max.controls = ratio,  :
  Found negative omit.fraction values, not currently supported

Answer (score 1):

Your issue seems to be kinda bug in MatchIt package as noted on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28138581/6574038) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32502078/6574038). I've submitted a [ticket on GitHub](https://github.com/kosukeimai/MatchIt/issues/18).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the `discard = "hull.control"` issue:

Download the source code of MatchIt from [here](https://github.com/cran/MatchIt) and edit **discard.R**. Add to the calls of `WhatIf::whatif` the argument `mc.cores = 1`. This should hard-code the number of cores used to 1 and thus eliminate the issue.

Uninstall the MatchIt package and build the new one by opening command line and type **R CMD build C:\path\to\MatchIt-master**. This should create a .tar.gz file. In R Studio, click on *Tools -> Install packages...* and select the local package.

You may need to restart R Studio if the library was loaded previously.

Enjoy.